# $dy/dx=e^{-y}$ differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential-equation: $$dy/dx=e^{-y}$$ 
This is what I tried:

[image]

However that is **not** a correct solution. How can I derrive the true solution?

This is not correct as:

[image]

*I forgot to write ln, the right side hasn't changed*

I used TI-Nspire CX CAS student software to come to that conclusion:
[image]

Weird it's given me a wrong answer

Comment: Why do you believe this is not correct? Mind the notation in the one but last line, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is not correct as:
>
> [image]

That derivative is wrong and why does the $\ln$ disappear in the exponent in the right-hand side?

If $y=\ln(x+c)$, then $y'=\tfrac{1}{x+c}$ but also:
$$e^{-y}=e^{-\ln(x+c)}=\frac{1}{e^{\ln(x+c)}}=\tfrac{1}{x+c}$$

---

The derivative of $\ln x$ is $\tfrac{1}{x}$ so then by the **chain rule**:
$$\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d}x}\ln(x+c)=\frac{1}{x+c}\underbrace{\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d}x}\left(x+c\right)}_{=1}=\frac{1}{x+c}$$

Comment: What went wrong for me was that I failed to differentiate y. Can you show, step by step, how you got $d[ln(x+c)]/dx$ to be equal to $1/(x+c)$ ?

Comment: @RyanCameron Derivative of $\ln |u|$ is $1/u \, \mathrm du$...

Comment: @RyanCameron I added a bit at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this is actually the right solution

$$
\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{1}{x + c} \tag{1}
$$

and

$$
e^{-y} = \frac{1}{e^y} = \frac{1}{e^{\ln(x + c)}} = \frac{1}{x + c} \tag{2}
$$

So yes, $y(x) = \ln |x + c|$ is the solution

Comment: What went wrong for me was that I failed to differentiate y. Can you show, step by step, how you got $d[ln(x+c)]/dx$ to be equal to $1/(x+c)$ ?

Comment: @RyanCameron It is just the derivative of $\ln$: $$\frac{{\rm d}\ln u(x)}{{\rm d} x} = \frac{1}{u(x)}\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x}$$